# Passing raw pointer to a function with shared_ptr

Tags: c++

When I have a function:

```
void foo(std::shared_ptr<T> a, std::shared_ptr<T> b);
```

is there a chance of memory leak when calling it like this:

```
foo(new T(), new T());
```

Comment: It can't throw because it won't compile. So you're safe.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That won't compile since the conversion to `shared_ptr` is explicit. If I were to naively fix that:

```
foo(std::shared_ptr<T>(new T()), std::shared_ptr<T>(new T()));  // don't do this
```

then there is indeed a chance of a memory leak. One allowed order of evaluation is:

```
T * p1 = new T();
T * p2 = new T();
std::shared_ptr<T> s1(p1);
std::shared_ptr<T> s2(p2);
foo(s1,s2);
```

If the second `new` throws an exception, then the first object would be leaked. To fix this, make sure the first shared pointer is initialised before attempting the second allocation, either with a temporary variable:

```
std::shared_ptr<T> a(new T());
std::shared_ptr<T> b(new T());
foo(a,b);
```

or calling a function to initialise each

```
foo(std::make_shared<T>(), std::make_shared<T>());
```

Comment: yes, won't compile. It is a "translation" from code with other smart pointer implementation that had no constructor marked explicit. But in any case, the point was in figuring evaluation order.

Answer (score 2):

As @Mike said, your source won't compile. You need an explicit construction of `shared_ptr`, such as:

```
foo(std::shared_ptr<T>(new T()), std::shared_ptr<T>(new T()));
```

It's still unsafe. In c++ expressions used as function arguments may generally be evaluated in any order, including interleaved, except as otherwise restricted by the other rules.

For one example, the order may be:

1. allocate memory for the first T
2. construct the first T
3. allocate memory for the second T
4. construct the second T
5. construct the shared_ptr
6. construct the shared_ptr

And if step(3) or (4) failed (by throwing), The object constructed at step(2) will not be destructed, and memory allocated at step(1) will leak.